# Declare of global variables using Static and avoiding Singleton Pattern

Tags: c++

I want to declare global variables , avoiding Singleton Pattern, using static variables like so, without encapsulation. The end goal is to be able to access the variables from any functions/objects like a global variable. The code can't compile at vec.pushback under main(), need help here. Any downside of the code? Can it be used in multithreaded environment ? Thanks.

```
struct Properties {
    static int roll;
    static std::string name;
    static std::vector<std::string> vec;
};

int Properties::roll = 1;
std::string Properties::name{};
std::vector < std::string > vec;

int main()
{
    Properties::roll = 1;
    Properties::name = "Jack";
    Properties::vec.push_back("Hellooooo"); // unresolved external symbol "public: static class 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `std::vector < std::string > vec;` should be `std::vector < std::string > Properties::vec;`

Comment: Above comment notwithstanding, the end goal is really unclear.

Comment: FWIW, If you want global objects, that are scoped to a name, then use a namespace, not a class/struct.

Comment: These are just global variables and have the same downsides. The only difference is that these will require more typing than if they were declared in global scope.

Comment: @NathanOliver: namespace seems like better idea.

Comment: But why this code doesn't compile?

Comment: Regarding downsides: it doesn't matter whether you hide your globals in a struct or in a namespace or inside a singleton – the problem is having globally shared mutable state, not the syntax that you use to access it.

Comment: Singleton or global variable == just different shades of bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why this code doesn't compile?

```
int Properties::roll = 1;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
std::string Properties::name{};
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
std::vector < std::string >             vec;
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You've correctly defined the other static members, but failed to define `Properties::vec`. Instead, you defined a global `::vec`.

> Any downside of the code?

Potentially: Static initialisation order fiasco. Now, these static objects don't depend on each other, but if you at any point wish to add static objects that depend on these static objects (in their constructor or destructor either directly or indirectly), then your program could have undefined behaviour depending on what order the objects are initialised.

It is best to avoid static objects when they're not necessary. Failing that, it is best to avoid dependencies between static objects, although such dependencies can sometimes be well hidden. Failing that, the way with least propensity to a fiasco is *initialisation on first use* idiom. Which is to simply use a local static instead of a namespace static or a static member:

```
struct Properties {
    int roll;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
};

Properties& static_properties() {
    static Properties prop;
    return prop;
}
```

---

> Can it be used in multithreaded environment ?

None of your static objects are atomic, so you would need some form of synchronisation between threads that modify the objects, and all other threads that access the objects.

Provided that you take care of synchronisation, and don't make assumptions about their state: Sure.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can guarantee that none of the static objects will ever be modified while a thread might be reading them (e.g. you modify them only during startup, before you spawn any threads), then they become effectively immutable, which means that threads can read them without having to do any synchronization.  (you might want to provide an accessor-API that enforces that read-only property at compile-time, though, to avoid the possibility of some programmer someday forgetting the rule and trying to modify them when he shouldn't)